# jQuery slidetoggle parent-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, parent-child, parent

I got a problem with my jQuery, I need a little help. Check the menu at the following [link](http://student.aii.avans.nl/cmd/shgzon/mediatech/).

I use slideToggle and when you press the first button it slideToggle a submenu (works fine). But I am finding a way to hide that submenu when the other button is pressed. (I tried a lot for solving it, I got close...) I tried toggling on that other button but it gets bugged somehow anyone ideas? I got the code here:

**jQuery:**

```
//select all the `<li>` element that are children of the `.parent` element
$('.parent').children().click(function(){

//now find the `.child` elements that are direct children of the clicked `<li>` and toggle it into or out-of-view
$(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow'); 


});
```

Comment: I would recommend adding identifiers on the other buttons because right now the click handler is being applied to every button, including the first one. Rather than doing `$(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow')`, you should make it so that when any button is clicked, it checks the id `nav-1` to see if its displayed. If it is, then run `slideToggle`

Comment: Oh and for future reference, avoid using absolute URLs to your website. Stackoverflow is meant to be an index and you might not have that site up for the rest of your life. People prefer jsFiddles.